# how can I count number of occurance of a word in a string while ignoring cases

Tags: php

I am trying to count the number of occurance of a given word while ignoring cases.
I have tried

```
<?php 
 $string = 'Hello World! EARTh in earth and EARth';//string to look into.
  if(stristr($string, 'eartH')) {
    echo 'Found';// this just show eartH was found.
  }
  $timesfound = substr_count($string, stristr($string, 'eartH'));// this count how many times. 

  echo $timesfound; // this outputs 1 instead of 3.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lowercase the string before searching:

```
$string = 'Hello World! EARTh in earth and EARth';
$search = 'EArtH';
var_dump(substr_count(strtolower($string), strtolower($search))); // outputs 3
```

Comment: ok this works but try searching for "EarTH" I don't think it will work.

Comment: @Ronny Didn't think that would be an issue, but I've updated my answer anyways.

Answer (score -1):

try substr_count()

```
     <?php
     $text = 'This is a test';
     echo strlen($text); // 14

    echo substr_count($text, 'is'); // 2

    ?>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and OP was using `substr_count` anyways.